# Move files from a drive tree to a single directory on another drive, renaming duplicates with a suffix

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I am using Python in Windows 10, and would like to find all .CSV files throughout my E: drive and move them to my D: drive into a single directory.

When a duplicate name is found, I would like it not to overwrite the existing file, but to add a unique suffix instead.

Example:

```
E:\
|---Folder 1
|       Book.CSV
|---Folder 2
|     \---Folder 2A
|             Book.CSV
```

mv

```
D:\ 
|---CSV Files
|       Book.CSV
|       Book_2.CSV
```

I have found the following 3 groups of code, and have tried a few variations which kind of worked, but renamed all of my files to the same name.

I'm wondering if someone could tell me how to put this combination together.

Script 1

```py
import glob
import os
import shutil

src_folder = r"E:\pynative\report"
dst_folder = r"E:\pynative\account\\"

# Search files with .txt extension in source directory
pattern = "\*.txt"
files = glob.glob(src_folder + pattern)

# move the files with txt extension
for file in files:
    # extract file name form file path
    file_name = os.path.basename(file)
    shutil.move(file, dst_folder + file_name)
    print('Moved:', file)
```

Script 2

```py
import os
import shutil

src_folder = r"E:\reports\\"
dst_folder = r"E:\pynative\account\\"
file_name = 'sales.csv'

# check if file exist in destination
if os.path.exists(dst_folder + file_name):
    # Split name and extension
    data = os.path.splitext(file_name)
    only_name = data[0]
    extension = data[1]
    # Adding the new name
    new_base = only_name + '_new' + extension
    # construct full file path
    new_name = os.path.join(dst_folder, new_base)
    # move file
    shutil.move(src_folder + file_name, new_name)
else:
    shutil.move(src_folder + file_name, dst_folder + file_name)
```

Script 3

```py
import shutil
import os

# Define the source and destination path
source = "Desktop/content/waste/"
destination = "Desktop/content/"

# code to move the files from sub-folder to main folder.
files = os.listdir(source)
for file in files:
    file_name = os.path.join(source, file)
    shutil.move(file_name, destination)
print("Files Moved")
```

I tried a combination of the 3, but could not figure out the correct layout to execute what I am looking for.